# Why is there a need for different exchanges?

Tags: exchanges

In laymen's terms, why is there a need for different bitcoin exchanges? Is it currently the wild west and eventually these exchanges will consolidate. Or can exchanges actually provide different value to their customers, justifying their existence. I ask  this because there are 100+ exchanges out there? Why doesn't everyone just flock to the most reputable and liquid one?

Comment: Why is there a need for different banks? For different grocery stores? Etc. Why doesn't everyone just flock to the most reputable and well stocked/cheapest grocery store?

Answer (score 3):

Different countries, different laws, different currencies, different banks, different payment systems.

Competition and free market.

No single central point of failure.